# Implicit grid area naming

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is it possible in CSS to use named grid areas i.e. `grid-area: 'a'` without having to declare each one?
I want to utilize this for the `grid-template-areas` declaration.

```css
.manSection {
  display: grid;
  height: 700px;
  width: 200px;
  grid-template-areas:
    ". a ."
    "b . c"
    ". d ."
    ". e ."
    ". f ."
    "k . g"
    "r . p"
    ". h .";
  row-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="manSection">
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible with current CSS unfortunately.

You would be able to write a sass function to loop through each span and give it a grid area with `:nth-child()` selectors but this would still result in the same CSS nonetheless.

I thought it might be possible with [counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters) to automatically go through each span and assign an explicit grid area, though the [grid area property](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-grid/#propdef-grid-area) won't accept string values so it's incompatible with counters. The following **doesn't work**:

```css
.manSection {
  display: grid;
  height: 700px;
  width: 200px;
  grid-template-areas:
    ". a ."
    "b . c"
    ". d ."
    ". e ."
    ". f ."
    "k . g"
    "r . p"
    ". h .";
  row-gap: 10px;
  counter-reset: mygrid;
}

.manSection > span {
  counter-increment: mygrid;
  grid-area: counter(mygrid, alphabetic);
}
```

```html
<section class="manSection">
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
</section>
```